# Immutability invariants in Haskell's GC, considering mutual recursion

Tags: haskell, memory, optimization, garbage-collection

I was reading this article: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Management
and found it a bit confusing. I do not understand the part:

> The trick is that immutable data NEVER points to younger values. Indeed, younger values don't yet exist at the time when an old value is created, so it cannot be pointed to from scratch. And since values are never modified, neither can it be pointed to later. This is the key property of immutable data.

I think it would be true if we forget about recursion and mutual recursion, but what about

```
let x = 1:y
    y = 2:x
```

which is proper Haskell code, and makes `x == [1,2,1...]`. Here `x` points to `y` and `y` points to `x`. In this situation we cannot say that no value points to younger one (one of them must actually be elder).

Who is mistaken - me, or article author? Why? How does immutability help GC's analysis in this case?

Comment: The wiki is probably simplifying a bit. My guess is that your assumption "one of them must actually be elder" does not apply here, and `x,y` have to be considered to be born at the same time. I'm not terribly familiar with the GHC GC to answer this more precisely.

Comment: Also, due to laziness, there is no infinite list until you try to force the entire list. `head x`, for example, never needs to evaluate `y`. Further, each use of `x` is a distinct value. It's not a circular list that reuses the same 1 and 2 over and over.

Comment: Immutable strict data never refers to younger values. The same is not true of lazy data, since laziness is implemented by mutating each thunk at most once.

Comment: That quote sounds like an over-simplification.  Thunks are frequently updated and might very well point to a younger generation.  It’s important to keep track of these references since they need to be scanned on a minor gc.

Comment: GHC’s RTS uses “remembered sets” to track these references from older generations to younger objects. For *strictly* evaluated immutable data, such references are impossible, as are reference cycles.

Comment: The referenced article is a poor article. It could use an edit job!